# When is the earliest humans could evolve?

Tags: humans, evolution, proto-human

There are many fantasy stories of humans living in the world with prehistoric animals, mainly stemming from the classic image of the cave man. Despite strong hopes, this is unrealistic as human evolution has been occurring for a measly two million years. But surely there are ways humans could evolve sooner.

Without messing with pre-primate evolution, when is the earliest humans could evolve in the prehistoric time scale? What if we mess around with evolution before primates?

Comment: This is just way too broad. Every branch in the "family tree"...

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/CollapsedtreeLabels-simplified.svg

...depends on the previous one. So there is no way you can suddenly decide to skip a few steps and think you will arrive at the same result, at least not with a "reality-check" tag. If you throw out "reality-check" you can just make up any family tree you want and shape it according to your whims as the author. So this makes the question very broad. Voting to close.

Comment: Looks like you want to build a fantasy world where the megafauna is part of the setting. Why mess with evolution, why not simply allow the megafauna to survive until, say, mediaeval times? Or, perhaps, riffing off @ErinThursby's answer, let writing be discovered earlier, and prehistory itself is history..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destruction of the dinosaurs allowed for the evolution of mammals. That destruction, according to what I have read, had a lot to do with weather changes. Mammals are better at regulating their body temperature, so cold weather wasn't the best for dinos. If you are building an earth-like world and wanting dinos to be concurrent with man, I'd say that there's a lot of changes that will need to be made. Best thing I can think of is places just on the edge of what dinos (and other mega beasts) can handle, that are isolated. But if they travel out of that area, where the worst beasts are, it will be very difficult for them to handle, as they haven't been in that environment before.

Also, man did exist with prehistoric animals. That's because the definition of prehistory is: before written records. We evolved before we started writing things down. There are some truly SCARY animals that were around in man's early days.

> Some of the most ferocious animals that once ate our kind are unlike any predators we contend with today. Even when they are reconstructed in museum exhibits, they appear more imaginary than real: giant hyenas, as mentioned, but also giant bears (Agriotherium), saber-toothed cats (Homotherium, Machairodus, Megantereon) and “false” saber-toothed cats (Dinofelis). In Australia, the first aboriginal colonists would have encountered giant, predatory kangaroos. Whether those roos proved deadly, we do not know. But imagine being chased by a giant hopping animal with six-inch-long teeth. Saber-toothed cats used their teeth to cut flesh, like pulling barbecue off a rib. In all likelihood, that flesh would have included that of our ancestors and kin, though the only evidence of their effects is from a single hominid skull bearing two holes, one for each saber.

Read more: [http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/the-top-ten-deadliest-animals-of-our-evolutionary-past-18257965/#AOkMIxOPJRa0OVcK.99](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/the-top-ten-deadliest-animals-of-our-evolutionary-past-18257965/?no-ist)

That being said, what I think you are asking covers a lot of ground. So there's far more than dinos in the realm of the prehistoric. It's very difficult to give you an exact date without knowing what you are aiming at.

I cannot see it happening on a global scale, but I can see it happening in a small place or an island.

An earlier evolution might include

- An isolated environment that doesn't allow most of these predators in, but has enough evolutionary "push" and stresses to encourage tool use.
- A place with different weather patterns which eliminates the big stressors.
- But it would have to have enough of a population to sustain numbers. Or, tragically, they all die and the evolution happens again, on a larger scale, around the time that we currently date it. (although, there is much argument on that).

Answer (score 2):

If by "pre-primate evolution", you mean the evolution of everything before primates appeared, then humans could have appeared 50-55 million years ago. If you go before that, humans would either die out or develop too rapidly and change the course of evolution before primates could have appeared.

Keep in mind that the humans that clearly displayed creative thinking lived only around 40,000 years ago. So, 40,000 years after humans appeared, the entire world is very different.